# ember-cli ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, macos, ember.js, ember-cli

Running following sequence of commands give an error on ember server :

```
npm install -g ember-cli
npm install -g bower
brew install watchman
npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
ember new my-new-app
cd my-new-app
ember server
```

Error is as below on Node 6.5.0 and npm 3.10.3 ->

```
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:564:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

Build successful - 36429ms.
```

Application starts up but how can this error be removed ?

**EDIT**

When ember server finishes fast, it runs without error however -